# Create Login command error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

What is wrong here in following screen shot? [image]

I am trying solutions posted [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/sqlman/archive/2011/06/14/tips-amp-tricks-you-have-lost-access-to-sql-server-now-what.aspx) and [here](http://v-consult.be/2011/05/26/recover-sa-password-microsoft-sql-server-2008-r2/) to add a login

Comment: The syntax looks totally OK. I tried the same command on my machine and it works. Since you seem to be in some kind of desaster recovery I wouldn't rule out that the server code itself was damaged. I would try some other commands like "select loginname, sysadmin from sys.syslogins" to see if anything works at all. Or you can try your luck with sp_addlogin (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173768%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: If you haven't done so already. cross post this on dba.stackexchange.com. It might be migrated anyway (not programming related).